# $F[x]$-modules isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, smith-normal-form

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field, and $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$.

Define $M,L=\mathbb F^n$ to be $\mathbb {F}[x]$-modules, s.t. for every $m\in M,l\in L$ :

$f(x)m=f(A)m$

$f(x)l=f(A^t)l$

Prove that both modules are isomorphic.

I proved that $xI-A$ and $xI-A^t$ have the same Smith Normal Form.

My question is how to prove that $M\cong L $ by that $SNF(xI-A)=SNF(xI-A^t)$?

Comment: Aren't $M,L$ isomorphic to cyclic modules whose annihilators are the invariant factors of  SNF?

Comment: Doesn't the SNF gives out the same  decomposition of $M, L$ into primary modules? The invariant factors are all the same.